# How do make users see users they are following posts show up on the post feed

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to allow users to see the post of users they are following. The problem is that only the logged in users post are showing on the feed. My following node on firebase looks like:

**Following Collection**

```
Following
     uid
        userA
        userB
```

**Post Collection**

```
Post
     uid
        images
              auto.id
                     caption
                     imageURL
```

**View Controller**

```
class WorkplsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var PostTable: UITableView!

var PostList = [PostCapModel]()

var ref = Database.database().reference()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    PostTable.dataSource = self
    PostTable.delegate = self

    ref.child("Post").child("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)").child("images").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        if let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            let Caption = postDict["imgCaption"] as? String
            let PostMedia = postDict["imgUrl"] as? String                
            self.PostList.append(PostCapModel(PostCaption: Caption, PostImage: PostMedia))
            self.PostTable.reloadData()
        }
    }

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return PostList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCellTableViewCell

    cell.CellLabel.text = PostList[indexPath.row].PostCaption
    cell.PostPic.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: PostList[indexPath.row].PostImage!))
    self.PostTable.reloadData()
     return cell
                }
```

Comment: Please upload your security rules.

Comment: my rules are     "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }}

Comment: You are attaching a listener to the current user's posts, not the post collection itself. You may need to redesign your database structure to listen for changes on all posts.

Comment: so should i be reading data from the following node?

Comment: I think that you may need to change the overall structure of your database and store the uid as part of the data in the node and not a `child` itself. This provides a flatter data structure and allows for obtaining data through queries.

Comment: alright thanks i will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to restructure your Posts node to something like this:

**Posts**

```
Posts
   postID
        author (uid)
        images
             imageID
                    caption
                    imageURL
```

This would allow you to attach a listener to the general `Posts` node, and not just a specific user's node.

```
ref.child("Posts").child(postID).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
      // Do Something  
}
```

In the future, if you wanted to see a list of posts from user's they are following you would create a branch under the `Users` node called `timeline` and whenever someone they follow posts something, you would use a function to add the postID to every follower's timeline (plus some meta-information such as a timestamp for sorting).

```
Users
   userID
        timeline
             postID1
                    timestamp (or some other information that doesn't change)
             postID2
                    timestamp
             postID3
                    timestamp
```

Then, you can attach a listener to the specific user's timeline and get all the posts from the people they're following.

```
ref.child("Users").child(userID).child("timeline").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
      // Get all posts from the Post node now that you have the postID's
}
```